# Почему локальная переменная не инициализируется с блока subscribe?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, rxjs

```
getItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
    return this.http.get<Item[]>('./assets/data/data.json');
}
```

У меня есть код, который возвращает Observable. Ниже другой компонент, в котором вызывается первая функция. Я подписываюсь и получаю данные.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.itemService.getItems().subscribe(i => this.items = i);

    console.log(this.items);
}
```

Но когда вызываю ту же функцию в сервисе, где написан метод, при инициализации локальной переменной она остаётся `undefined`

```
let items: Item[];
...

    this.getItems().subscribe(i => items = i);
```

При отладке `console.log()` в блоке `subscribe()` данные все есть.
В чём проблема? Читал несколько статей, в одной парень расписал всё детально. Но я так и не понял в чём проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что `subscribe` это асинхронная функция, которая не обязательно вызовется перед `console.log` (а вероятнее всего, в реальном проекте, после). Надо делать так:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.itemService.getItems().subscribe(
        i => {
            this.items = i;
            console.log(this.items);
        }
    );    
}
```

Смысл данной конструкции в том, чтобы сделать запрос данных (например, с сервера) и, не дожидаясь ответа (и не блокируя выполнение кода приложения), продолжить выполнение программы дальше без задержек. Когда данные будут получены вызовется метод `subscribe` объекта класса `Observable`